# Правильно ли составлено предложение по смыслу и пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

На мансардном этаже, из окна лился желтоватый, чуть тускнеющий при появлении в оконном проёме темно - серой фигуры, свет!

Comment: Прямо стихи какие-то: на манасардном этаже / из Окна лился желтоватый / чуть тусклый в появленье свет / фигуры серой, в тёмной раме.

Answer (score 0):

1. После указания места не нужна запятая.
2. Цвет (тёмно-серый) пишется через дефис, лучше убрать пробелы.
3. После слова "фигуры" запятая не понадобится. Главное слово стоит после причастного оборота.
4. Восклицательный знак в конце предложения кажется лишним.

На мансардном этаже из окна лился желтоватый, чуть тускнеющий при появлении в оконном проёме тёмно-серой фигуры свет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ещё поправь, Артём: *запятая не понадобятся*.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова
По поводу обособления причастного оборота. Правила Розенталя. § 22, п.4, примечание 1, §10, п.7. Обособление оборота допускается:  Пьер, с раннего утра уже стянутый в неловком, сделавшемся ему узким, дворянском мундире, был в залах. Особенно это касается  такого распространенного оборота. Кстати, неплохо бы поставить его после определяемого слова, здесь он явно не на месте.

Comment: Ой! А я вроде бы про причастный оборот ничего не говорила.

Comment: А почему запятую убрали?   И почему нельзя так написать: На мансардном этаже из окна лился желтоватый свет, чуть тускнеющий при появлении в оконном проёме темно-серой фигуры.

Comment: Sharon, это ведь не мой ответ, и я ниоткуда ничего не убирала. Я просто попросила Артёма (так как именно он делал правку ответа участника *ALTrueYST*) исправить ещё одну неточность: *запятая не понадобятся* (поменять множественное число на единственное). Что он и сделал. Вот и всё.

Comment: Судя по вопросу в заголовке,  автор просил проверить пунктуацию и грамматику. Судя по ответу, отвечающий не видит однородных или уточняющих определений вообще, объяснения дает невнятные  Кто-нибудь может дать НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ ответ?  (Я с этими автором, который меняет приемку ответов,  больше не работаю.) Дайте ПОЛНЫЙ  ответ вы или еще кто-нибудь, разве мало специалистов на форуме

Answer (score 0):

Я обращу внимание на такие неточности.

В одном недлинном предложении: *из **окна** лился* и *в **оконном** проёме*.

Желтоватый свет (как и любой другой) никак не может тускнеть от появления кого-либо в проёме окна. Представьте, что вы закрываете половину окна плотной шторой или жалюзи. От этого интенсивность (или, если хотите, яркость) света, поступающего в помещение, не изменяется, а уменьшается только его *количество*. Так что нельзя говорить, что желтоватый свет тускнел (или был тускнеющим).

Теперь об определяемом слове "свет" в конце предложения.
Такие конструкции встречаются, читать их — не очень *удобственно*. Именно из-за этого я и запомнила автора, часто использующего такие обороты, и быстренько нашла (запятой перед "мне" нет, но она, конечно же, может быть; это — авторское решение):

> Оскаленные волчьи морды, мускулистые человеческие торсы, покрытые густой шерстью, ветер, китайским драконом вьющийся среди бойцов, семеро серых волков и трое красно-кирпичных койотов, которые прорывались к лежащей на полу и прижимающей к груди свой объемный рюкзак **мне**.

Итог: надо предложение изменять.

[тускнеть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)
[Елена Звездная. Шепот в темноте](https://litportal.ru/avtory/elena-zvezdnaya/read/page/3/kniga-shepot-v-temnote-972222.html)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант редактирования:

*Из окна, на мансардном этаже, лился желтоватый свет, чуть тускнеющий **при перемещении в комнате темно-серой фигуры.***

Сравнить (предыдущие правки на БВ): *Из окна мансарды лился желтоватый свет, тускнеющий при появлении в оконном проёме тёмно-серой фигуры.*

**Пояснение**

(1) Темно-серая фигура не появляется в окне или в оконном проеме – это **неточное** выражение.

(2) **Распространенный** оборот лучше поставить **после** определяемого слова.

(3) Уточнение (*из окна, на мансардном этаже*) используется, если оно требуется по контексту, в противном случае лучше сказать: *из окна мансарды*.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, мне это предложение показалось интересным.