# Склонение топонимов во множественном числе

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Предложение: «Возле сёл Партизанское (го) и Константиновка». Склоняются ли топонимы во множественном числе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Возле сёл Партизанское и Константиновка.***

Могу предположить, что названия не склоняются (в том числе по слуху).

**Причины следующие:**

(1) Родовое слово **в форме мн.числа** не согласуется с названиями, так что склонять их нет смысла (нет очевидной сочетаемости).

(2) **Род** у топонимов разный; кроме того, первое название имеет форму прилагательного.

(3) Сочетание похоже на географическое описание или военную хронику; в любом случае название не склоняется **в спец. литературе**, когда важно обеспечить его точность.

Answer (score 0):

С родовым словом "село" топоним [согласуется](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/), из чего можно сделать вывод, что и два топонима согласуются.
Представим ситуацию не с названиями, а с именами: *Мы прокрались мимо сторожей Сеньки и Ваньки.* Не пишем же: *...мимо сторожей Сенька и Ванька*.

Comment: Пжста, посмотрите мою правку предложения https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471275/Правильно-ли-составлено-предложение-по-смыслу-и-пунктуации   Как бы вы описали явление?

Comment: @Sharon Вариант ваш нормальный, но сам исходный материал, то есть предложение, не слишком хорошо сконструирован, так что как его ни крути, а улучшить можно лишь переписыванием)

Comment: Я просто видела все предыдущие правки, но везде фигура появлялась в окне. Но это же неверно. А что в этом предложении еще неправильно?

Comment: @Sharon суть в том, что из окна мансарды лился свет, который чуть тускнел, когда между источником света и окном оказывалась фигура. Теперь это надо изложить литературно, то есть красиво. В вашем варианте получается, что свет тускнел, когда фигура перемещалась -- это вызывает ряд вопросов: она что, перемещалась с такой скоростью, что засасывала фотоны, отчего свет и тускнел?)) Причина-то потускнения не в том, что фигура перемещалась, а в том, что оказывалась, как я выше сказал, между источником света и окном. Продолжу ниже.

Comment: @Sharon у автора, конечно, косяк помощнее: свет чуть тускнел, когда фигура появлялась в окне. Из этого вывод: фигура была полупрозрачная? Или как, почему свет лишь чуть тускнел, когда она его загораживала? Неясно...

Comment: @Sharon По итогу: *Из окна мансарды лился желтоватый свет, тускнеющий на миг, когда за стеклом кто-то проходил*. Немного сложнее: *Из окна мансарды лился желтоватый свет, прерывался на миг, когда за стеклом кто-то проходил: казалось, этим окном дом сонно помаргивает*. И совсем изощрённо: *Из окна мансарды торчал косой параллелепипед света, и когда за стеклом кто-то проходил, внутри параллелепипеда прогребал от грани до грани гротескно растянутый, будто прямиком с дыбы, силуэт*.

Comment: Мой вариант: «Из окна, на мансардном этаже, лился желтоватый свет, чуть тускнеющий при перемещении в комнате темно-серой фигуры». Ну вот, а я ожидала от вас похвалы, как Гринев от Швабрина, но вы оказались тонким ценителем литературы. Я все же объясню вам суть явления. Конечно, фотоны тут ни при чем. Когда фигура появлялась и перемещалась в проеме окна, то становилась экраном, что выглядело как перемещение тени фигуры. При перемещении тень меняла очертание, что сказывалось на освещенности. Их окна лился  не полный поток света, а ограниченный. А как передать, что тень не стояла, а двигалась.

Comment: Вот ваш вариант «Из окна мансарды лился желтоватый свет, тускнеющий на миг, когда за стеклом кто-то проходил".  А если он останавливался? И я сомневаюсь, что «стекло» вместо окна  – это хорошо.  Звучит странно и уж, конечно, очень буднично. У меня явление описано менее точно, более обобщенно, но очень поэтично. Но от вашего третьего варианта я пришла в совершенный восторг – какая фантазия, какие формы. Вы могли бы возглавить новое направление в литературе – успех был бы потрясающий. Как бы его только назвать? Кажется, у нас давно не было конкурсов, как вы считаете? Могу пожертвовать 150 у.е.

Comment: @Sharon если принципиально, что кто-то останавливался, то образ надо корректиррвать и предложение переписывать. А если не принципиально, то незачем и городить. // Яркий и длинно описанный образ — это конфетка; но когда конфеток чрезмерно, начинается диабет. Я к тому, что зачастую образы приходится упрощать, прореживать, и будничная фраза оказывается намного уместнее. // Я сторонник того, чтобы поэтичность не была в ущерб точности.

Comment: Но у меня ведь тоже коротко, а смысл вполне ясен. Иногда детальная прорисовка  ухудшает качество текста, здесь нужна золотая середина. Кстати, свидетели голосуют, а за что?  За ваш вариант или хотят конкурса.

Comment: @Sharon на мой взгляд, у вас недостачно ясно, к тому же 'при перемещении' отдаёт канцелярщиной. Впрочем, как я и сказал, ваш вариант нормален.